# Recreate Semantic Dropdown Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using [Semantic-Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#behavior) and I'm trying to recreate the dropdown with new options that I get from AJAX. I believe I only need to change the actual `select` element then refresh the dropdown [as mentioned here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4083) but I can't make it work.

#### HTML

```
<select name="group" id="first">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button>Change the Dropdown</button>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").dropdown();

  $("button").click(function() {
    var newSelect = "<select name='group' id='second'>";
    newSelect += "<option value='4'>4</option>";
    newSelect += "<option value='5'>5</option>";
    newSelect += "<option value='6'>6</option>";
    newSelect += "</select>";
    $("select").replaceWith(newSelect);

    // $("select").dropdown("setup menu"); // dropdown.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefine
    $("select").dropdown("refresh"); // no error but doesn't change the dropdown
    // $("select").dropdown("refresh menu"); // no error but doesn't change the dropdown
  });
});
```

And for you to test it out: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wypzzzgw/2/)

The script above does replace the old `select` but the UI for the dropdown doesn't update and displays the old `options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use 'setup select' to recreate the dropdown

```
$('select').dropdown('setup select');
```